# ¿Como saber cuando se ha hecho click sobre un boton, que fue generado dinamicamente en JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web implementando `HTML`, `JAVASCRIPT`, `JQUERY`

Desde `JAVASCRIPT`, estoy agregando codigo `HTML`, para generar botones, conforme los necesite, dentro de un `for`, pero solo añado como lo estoy agregando con el siguiente código:

```
x +="<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn boton-eliminar-tratamiento\" name=\"DIENTE-1-TRATAMIENTO-1"\" >ELIMINAR</button>";
document.getElementById("p-tratamientos").innerHTML = x;
```

Hasta ahí todo me funciona bien. Los botones si aparecen en el HTML. Mi problema es cuando ahora quiero ver si el usuario apretó dicho botón. Lo intente con el siguiente codigo:

```
$(".boton-eliminar-tratamiento").click(function(){
    alert('Ha hecho click sobre el boton'); 
    return true; 
});
```

En teoría debería hacerlo, pero estoy casi seguro que tiene que ver que el botón lo genere de manera dinámica desde `JS` con el `innerHTML` y por eso no entra al `click`.

Comment: tu código funciona perfectamente solo que al final agregas por error 2 comillas ...`-1-TRATAMIENTO-1"\" >ELIMINAR`...

Comment: entiendo que tiene respuesta y la aprobacion y todo, pero lo que no logro entender es el porque del titulo. "¿Como obtener el name de un button cuando a este se le da click?".. Lo correcto no seria mejor "¿Como saber cuando se ha hecho click sobre un boton?" o algo parecido.

Comment: @PabloContreras tienes razón colega, ya lo corregí... Es que una de mis dudas también tenia que ver con eso. Gracias por hacérmelo notar

Comment: Ok hermano, tranquilo de nada, para eso estamos :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba cambiando tu porción de código:

```
$(".boton-eliminar-tratamiento").click(function(){
    alert('Ha hecho click sobre el boton'); 
    return true; // TIP: esto no es necesario de todas formas
});
```

A este código, el cual vendría siendo un ***[delegated event listener](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)*** (enlace en inglés):

```
$(document).on('click', '.boton-eliminar-tratamiento', function(){
    alert('Ha hecho click sobre el boton'); 
});
```

Cuando creas elementos dinámicamente y los añades al árbol del `DOM` estos no son escuchados por `jquery` mediante el común `$('selector')`, por lo tanto debes usar el *delegated event listener* con el `$(document).on('event', 'selector', callback)` como te muestro en el ejemplo anterior.

Comment: Solución correcta, gracias colega

Answer (score 0):

tu código funciona perfectamente solo que al final agregas por error 2 comillas: "...`-1-TRATAMIENTO-1"\" >ELIMINAR`..." aquí te dejo tu código con una pequeña modificación en el literal asignado a **x**:

```js
x='<button type="button" class="btn boton-eliminar-tratamiento" name="DIENTE-1-TRATAMIENTO-1">ELIMINAR</button>';
document.getElementById("p-tratamientos").innerHTML = x;

$(".boton-eliminar-tratamiento").click(function(){
    alert('Ha hecho click sobre el boton'); 
    return true; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="p-tratamientos"></div>
```